# Php image drawing using submitted word

Tags: php, get, draw

I'm trying to create image in php (see Result)

## 1 - input by sumbiting any word

(in this case it's ABABAABABAB)

[Result:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xgq4Q.jpg)

The image changes according to the length of the word

- if the sum of char of the word isn't odd the middle part stays empty.
- the longer/shorter the word the more/less cycles inside the drawing

The algorithm shouldn't be a problem, but the real problem is getting the input(word)and then drawing ANYTHING.

"Crash" resized to 500%  [Crash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mn6IV.jpg)

Image code:

```
<?php 
      $n=$_GET["word"]; // this is the part which "crashes" 
      header('Content-type: image/png');
      $png_image = imagecreate(150, 150);

      imagecolorallocate($png_image, 255, 255, 255);
      imagesetthickness($png_image, 5);
      $black = imagecolorallocate($png_image, 0, 0, 0);

      $x = 0;
      $y = 0;
      $w = imagesx($png_image) - 1;
      $z = imagesy($png_image) - 1;
  for($i=0; $i<4; $i++){    

  imageline($png_image, $x+$i*20, $y-20+$i*20, $x+$i*20, $y+$z-$i*20, $black);      
  imageline($png_image, $x+18+$i*20, $y+20*$i, $x+$w-20*$i, $y+20*$i, $black); 
  imageline($png_image, $x+$w-$i*20, $y+$i*20, $x+$w-$i*20, $y+$z-$i*20, $black); 
  imageline($png_image, $x+$i*20, $y+$z-$i*20, $x+$w-$i*20 ,$y+$z-$i*20, $black);
    }

      imagepng($png_image);

      imagedestroy($png_image);
    ?>
```

I'm including the "sumbit page" here:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html> 
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main1.css" />   
<title>In</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="image.php" method="get">
Slovo: <input type="text" name="word"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

## the real problem appears when I try to use a submited word using

$n=$_GET["word"];

After that the drawing changes into a never changing object and therefore I cannot draw anything.

Any suggestions how to fix that?

Also, if anyone is willing the whole .php solution is welcome.

THANKS!

Comment: Are you assigning the width of the image to `$w` and **also** assigning the passed-in word to `$w`?

Comment: That shouldn't be the issue - I changed the name of the variable when posting here, originally the variable was named $n, thanks for the tip tho, I will edit it

Comment: It would be useful to see the code that is failing.

Comment: Ok I will add more info in a minute

Comment: Did a simple test, change your parameter name from "word" to "word1" (or something different) and test again. I think that will clear up your issue of the "crash"

Comment: I'm going to kill myself... Thanks alot! Back to the algorithm then :)

Comment: I hate to say it again, but now it "crashes" after trying to write the String 

imageString($png_image, 5, 15, 50, $n[i], $black);  

which is inside the for cycle